# Drupal 7 Feeds module not deleting nodes after removed from XML

Tags: xml, drupal-7, drupal-feeds

Hi I have content being imported from and XML feed and updating from that feed too. This is all working fine but how do I set it to delete the content that no longer exist in the feed?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the nodes to expire a day or so after your periodic import. That way the old nodes will fizzle out while the constantly updated ones will continue thriving.

Those changes can be made in Feed's "Node Import" settings and "Basic settings" respectively.

A side note:

If you're just doing one import at a time, then go to the import page, select "Delete", that will remove ALL imported items from that specific feed and then reimport.

Answer (score 1):

See also the proposed patch "Unpublish/Delete nodes not included in feed" https://drupal.org/node/1470530